# vb.net Response on TCP client randomly gets delayed

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcpclient

Application processing data requests data from another server, generally the response is instant.

Once in a very great while it takes 4 minutes to get the response.  The host server it connects to logs the 4 minute case to have been responded to instantly on its end.  So something seems to cause the local application to take 4 minutes to processes or handle the response.

The problem seems to only occur when malware bytes is running on the host system it requests the data from.

Here is my code for sending a request for data.

```
    Public Function GetResponse(ByVal msg As String) As String
    'if calling this routine the calling routine needs to account for this throwing errors
    'generally the errors thrown would be connection related

    Dim tmpresponse As String = "noresponse"
    Dim bWriteBuffer() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim readbuffer As Byte() = New Byte(2000) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0


    Using oClient As New TcpClient
            bWriteBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg)
            oClient.Connect(RemoteEndPoint)
            Using tmpstream As NetworkStream = oClient.GetStream
                    tmpstream.Write(bWriteBuffer, 0, bWriteBuffer.Length)

                    '//blocks until a client sends a message 
                    bytesRead = tmpstream.Read(readbuffer, 0, 2000)
            tmpresponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readbuffer)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return tmpresponse
End Function
```